# cordova-plugin-facebook4 login error

Tags: facebook, cordova, cordova-plugins

i have just installed cordova and im writing my first app, and installed this plugin "cordova-plugin-facebook4", on my first test when i put the plugin login code right after:  onDeviceReady it displayed the facebook login once i run the command "cordova run android", however i created an events.js file and im making tests to fire the facebook login on a click event with no luck, when i click i get the following error->

```
events.js:10 Uncaught ReferenceError: facebookConnectPlugin is not defined
at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (events.js:10)
at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery-2.2.4.js:4737)
at HTMLButtonElement.elemData.handle (jquery-2.2.4.js:4549)
```

here i attach my code

index.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
    Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
    or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
    distributed with this work for additional information
    regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
    to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
    "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
    with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

    Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
    software distributed under the License is distributed on an
    "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
     KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
    specific language governing permissions and limitations
    under the License.
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <!--
        Customize this policy to fit your own app's needs. For more guidance, see:
            https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist/blob/master/README.md#content-security-policy
        Some notes:
            * gap: is required only on iOS (when using UIWebView) and is needed for JS->native communication
            * https://ssl.gstatic.com is required only on Android and is needed for TalkBack to function properly
            * Disables use of inline scripts in order to mitigate risk of XSS vulnerabilities. To change this:
                * Enable inline JS: add 'unsafe-inline' to default-src
        -->
        <!--<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; img-src 'self' data: content:;">-->
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">      
        <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="app">
            <h1>Apache Cordova</h1>
            <!--<div id="deviceready" class="blink">
                <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
                <p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>
            </div>-->
            
            <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
                <button id="loginFb">Facebook Login</button>
            </div>    
        </div>
        <script
        src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"
        integrity="sha256-iT6Q9iMJYuQiMWNd9lDyBUStIq/8PuOW33aOqmvFpqI="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/events.js"></script>        
    </body>
</html>
```

index.js:

```js
/*
 * Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
 * or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
 * distributed with this work for additional information
 * regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
 * to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
 * "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
 * with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
 * software distributed under the License is distributed on an
 * "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
 * KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
 * specific language governing permissions and limitations
 * under the License.
 */
var app = {
    // Application Constructor
    initialize: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady.bind(this), false);
    },

    // deviceready Event Handler
    //
    // Bind any cordova events here. Common events are:
    // 'pause', 'resume', etc.
    onDeviceReady: function() {
        this.receivedEvent('deviceready');    
        
        
                
        
    },

    // Update DOM on a Received Event
    receivedEvent: function(id) {
        var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
        var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
        var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

        listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
        receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

        console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
    }
};

app.initialize();
```

events.js:

```js
$(document).ready(function(e){
  $('#loginFb').click(function(){

  alert("alert");        
  
        var fbLoginSuccess = function (userData) {
          console.log("UserInfo: ", userData);
        }
        
        facebookConnectPlugin.login(["public_profile"], fbLoginSuccess,
          function loginError (error) {
            console.error(error)
          }
        );                  
    
  })             
});
```

Can someone please point me into the right direction? i need the facebook login to get fired on the click of the button

Comment: so why not define the click handler after deviceready? i don´t use cordova anymore (because it´s pretty much dead with stuff like react native), but if it worked before then that´s your answer. my personal suggestion though: forget about jquery and cordova and move up to react native with vanilla js.

Comment: Hello. thanks for your answer. just changed it to a plain click on old school js and it displays the same error:
Uncaught ReferenceError: facebookConnectPlugin is not defined

Comment: of course, that´s just an improvement but it does not solve the problem. did you try using  onDeviceReady again?

Comment: @luschn following your suggestion as soon as i removed the jquery and test it with the emulator it did work. Thanks!